# Create labels at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, label

With this code I can create labels at runtime:

```
ArrayList CustomLabel = new ArrayList();

foreach (string ValutaCustomScelta in Properties.Settings.Default.ValuteCustom)
{
     CustomLabel.Add(new Label());
     (CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Location = new System.Drawing.Point(317, 119 + CustomLabel.Count*26);
     (CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Parent = tabPage2;
     (CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Name = "label" + ValutaCustomScelta;
     (CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Text = ValutaCustomScelta;
     (CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 21);
     Controls.Add(CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Control);
}
```

I need create labels on tabPage2, but this row not work:

```
 (CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Parent = tabPage2;
```

Which is the correct instruction to create label on tabPage2 at runtime? (Im using visual studio 2010, windows form)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the labels to the `Controls` collection of the tab page:

```
tabPage2.Controls.Add(CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Control);
```

BTW: You shouldn't be using `ArrayList`. Instead use a `List<Label>`. Furthermore, first initialize the label, than add it to the list. This makes your code a lot more readable:

```
List<Label> customLabels = new List<Label>();

foreach (string ValutaCustomScelta in Properties.Settings.Default.ValuteCustom)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(317, 119 + customLabels.Count*26);
    label.Parent = tabPage2;
    label.Name = "label" + ValutaCustomScelta;
    label.Text = ValutaCustomScelta;
    label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 21);
    customLabels.Add(label);
    tabPage2.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: Daniel, only a little problem: in tabPage 2 I have an groupbox that hide labels created. How Can I place labels in "front of groupbox"?

Comment: @vincenzolopalo: You can use `tabPage2.SetChildIndex(label, 0)` or actually add the labels to the group box: `tabPage2.YourGroupBox.Controls.Add(label)`. Make sure that you specify the group box to be public in its properties.

Comment: I tryed but not work: tabPage2.groupBox3.Controls.Add(label);
in this way work: tabPage2.Controls.SetChildIndex(label, 0);
thanks for your important support Daniel!

Comment: @vincenzolopalo: `tabPage2.groupBox3.Controls.Add(label);` should work if you make sure the `Modifier` property of the group box is set to Public in the Properties window inside the designer.

Comment: I did so (public modifiers of groupBox3), but tabPage2.groupBox3... get me error in visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @vincenzolopalo: Yes, you are correct. `groupBox3` won't be created as a variable of `tabPage2`. Try this: `groupBox3.Controls.Add(label);`