# Method to create and change label

Tags: c#

I want to create label and set the text using method but it wont work, here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        intro();
    }
    private void fullScreen()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }
    private void intro()
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        pictureBox1.SendToBack();
        Label introInfo = new Label();
        introInfo.Font = new Font("century gothic", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
        introInfo.ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
        introInfo.Text = "succes bro!";
        introInfo.Visible = true;
        introInfo.Location = new Point(100, 100);            
    }        
}
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `label` to the `form`

```
this.Controls.Add(label);
```

Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439733/create-labels-at-runtime)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        intro();
    }

    private void fullScreen()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }

    private void intro()
    {
        Label introInfo = new Label();
        introInfo.Font = new Font("century gothic", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
        introInfo.ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
        introInfo.Text = "succes bro!";
        introInfo.Visible = true;
        introInfo.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        introInfo.Height = 35;
        introInfo.Width = 250;

        this.Controls.Add(introInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i add this.Controls.Add(label); ?

Comment: like this? '        private void intro()
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            pictureBox1.SendToBack();
            Label introInfo = new Label();
            introInfo.Font = new Font("century gothic", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
            introInfo.ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
            introInfo.Text = "succes bro!";
            introInfo.Visible = true;
            introInfo.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(introInfo);
        }'

Comment: but why in my form, i can't see the label ?

Comment: You also have to specify the label dimensions, copy the above code and it will work.

Comment: and how to use method intro(); when the form is load?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add newly created label to the control collection

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        intro();
    }
    private void fullScreen()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }


    private void intro()
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        pictureBox1.SendToBack();
        Label introInfo = new Label();
        introInfo.Font = new Font("century gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        introInfo.ForeColor = Color.Cyan;
        introInfo.Text = "succes bro!";
        introInfo.Visible = true;
        introInfo.Location = new Point(75, 23);
        introInfo.Size= new Size(100,100);
        this.Controls.Add(introInfo);
    }
```

Comment: it's working when i use button click event. but how to do that on form when load?

Comment: @notAdmin: I tried this and it is working for me. Could you try to change the Location of label.

Comment: it's work, now i want use method intro(); when the form1 is started. can i do that?

Comment: @notAdmin: Yes, you can very well use the form load event for that purpose.